# Add # character to url address with htaccess file?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With an htaccess file can I alter the destination of incoming links to add a # character?

If someone navigates to mysite.com/page2 I need them to be directed to mysite.com/#page2.

Comment: You will need to use a redirect or a rewrite (with redirection).  There are hundreds of questions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /#$1 [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Will this always remove the # symbol? I have many pages, I just used page2 as an example.

Comment: `remove the # symbol?` I think you want to add `#` symbol in certain pages right?

Comment: Also for several pages you can have rule as: `RewriteRule ^(page2|page3|page5|page11|page18)/?$ /#$1 [L,NE,R]`

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean add the #. How can I make the rule add the symbol to every page?